# How to loop through nested struct fields in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, struct

I have data on several subjects that each performed several trials of an activity.  I have read all the data into structs in the format
    subject(1).trial(1).something
    subject(1).trial(2).somethingelse
etc.

Now I need to read each of the trials into a row a big matrix [A] to perform some calculations on each trial, as if the subject didn't matter.  So I started with this:

```
for i = 2:numSubjects
    for j = 1:numTrials
    A(j,:) = cat(2,subject(i).trial(j).torque_integral,     subject(i).trial(j).work_integral); 
    end
end
```

But this will only work for the first subject.  When the subject (i) increments to 3, the trial (j) will be back at one.  So the idea is the output A lines up like this:

subject|trial|A

1          1        1

1          2        2

1          3        3

2          1        4

2          2        5

2          3        6

Hopefully this is clear.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like the loop is iterating through each subject (ignoring the first), and then each trial for each subject.  The code generally matches the output which matches what I might want to do with this loop.  What do you want to do?  Can you post an table of what you want to see (subject, trial)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i read your question correctly, you need to put each trial in one row, so when make your A variable, instead of using j as index, just use a new index...
lol seems like someone just posted the same thing before me...

```
m=1
for i = 2:numSubjects
    for j = 1:numTrials
       A(m,:) = cat(2,subject(i).trial(j).torque_integral,subject(i).trial(j).work_integral);
       m=m+1; 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand everything you do or want to do, but obviously if you have two `for` loops, of which the inner one starts with 1 it will start with one for each increment of the outer...

How about:

```
k=0;
for i = 2:numSubjects
    for j = 1:numTrials
    k=k+1;
    A(k,:) = cat(2,subject(i).trial(j).torque_integral,     subject(i).trial(j).work_integral); 
    end
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes thanks! i knew it was easy just couldn't wrap my head around it